# aysnch:false takes long to load async true returns undefined angularjs ng-show

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello am aving a problem with this code, it hangs the user browser which isn't good from the end user's perspective.. but turning the async to true returns undefined because the server isnt in a ready state to return the responseText.. wi ld really like someone to give me an idea of ow to resturcture this code.. because its being performed in the html ng-show @ the font end

controller:

```
$scope.votecheck = function(item,emailid){
    var email = emailid;
    if( typeof item !== 'undefined')
    {
   var jsonData = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
          url: 'ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email,
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false
            }).responseText;

if(jsonData === "CanVote"){

    return true;
}
else{

    return false;
        }   //return "canvote";
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-show="!votecheck(item,me.email)">
<p class="contest-text voters"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block img-rounded" ng-disabled="true"><b>Thanks For Voting</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-show="votecheck(item,me.email)">
<p class="contest-text voters"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block img-rounded" ng-click="upVote(item,me.email);"><b> VOTE</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

php:

```
<?php
include('../include/connect.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$emailid = $_GET['email'];
$query="select * from voters  where votedid='$id' and votersemail ='$emailid'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$rowcount = $result->num_rows;
if($rowcount === 0)
{
echo "CanVote";
}
else{
    echo "cantvote";
}

?>
```

thanx guyz

Answer (score 0):

Are you comibining jquery and the angular? Angular is asynchronous by nature and simple $http.get with a promise can solve the issue.

```
 your parameters should be passed here.
 var url = 'ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email;
 $http.get('url')
 .success(function(data)
 {

   // do your operarion here;
  })
.error(function(data){
//do what ever u want on error.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesnt it returns undefined den d value and all over again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `$http` service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and not `$.ajax`.

If i understood what you were trying to do, then you should not show the "vote" link until you are sure that the current user is able to vote. This can be done this way:

```
// TODO : fill canVote object with your item list,
// I guess you're using ng-repeat, and have an array of items.
// This object will be used to determine if the user can vote or not.
// Key : item ; value : boolean
$scope.canVote = {
  item1: false
};    
$scope.votecheck = function(item,emailid){
    var email = emailid;
    if( typeof item !== 'undefined')
    {
      $http.get('ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email).then(
         function cb_success(response) {
           $scope.items[item] = response.data === "CanVote";
      }, function cb_failure(response) {
           console.error(response);
      });
    }
}
angular.forEach($scope.canVote, function (status, item) {
  $scope.votecheck(item, $scope.me.email);
});
```

This is how you should do with your html :

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-show="canVote[item]">
    <p class="contest-text voters"><a class="btn btn-info btn-block img-rounded" ng-disabled="true"><b>Thanks For Voting</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-show="canVote[item]">
    <p class="contest-text voters"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block img-rounded" ng-click="upVote(item,me.email);"><b> VOTE</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
```

Since you did not provide any JSFiddle (w/e), I haven't been able to test it. Let me know if you have some issues.

Comment: thanx GeoffreyB.. using your code it returns  TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.. the email i passed in my code is actually generated from facebook login users

Comment: well, you old `me.email`, used in your `ng-show` directive should be stored somewhere and used correctly.

Comment: am preety new to angularjs.. can u pleaase just give me an exact code on how this wld work?..

Comment: can u make a working fiddle with the email passed in as parameer?

Comment: i ge tthis erros again TypeError: Cannot set property 'item1' of undefined
    at cb_success (controller.js:224)
    at l.promise.then.F (angular.min.js:100)
    at l.promise.then.F (angular.min.js:100)
    at angular.min.js:101
    at k.$get.k.$eval (angular.min.js:112)
    at k.$get.k.$digest (angular.min.js:109)
    at k.$get.k.$apply (angular.min.js:112)
    at h (angular.min.js:72)
    at u (angular.min.js:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onreadystatechange (angular.min.js:79)

Comment: You should be the one making a fiddle so i can show you how this should work. I have no idea about what you're doing beside this. Anyway, the clue here is to set a boolean to `true` or `false` according to the `CanVote` answer from your server.

Comment: am rilly preety new to this and i dont understand how to make a fiddle just yet with my code.. i found a way of putting the email inside the same controller but stil returns email undefined :(